# What is the difference between PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE and PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE in CMake?

Tags: cmake

When loading packages using `find_package(...)` in cmake the version file has to declare 5 variables. Two of them are

- PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE
- PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE

according to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages) they are used for

> PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE
>
> True if version is compatible
>
> PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE
>
> True if unsuitable as any version

Which leaves me puzzled. `PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE` has been introduced in CMake 2.6.2 . However it seems mutually exclusive to `PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE`. So why does it exist?

Can somebody enlighten me about the difference between being compatible and (un)suitable and maybe give an example, where both values are either `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, but for the sake of great justice:
There are three variables checking version:
`PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT`, `PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE` and `PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE`.

You can find logic behind this variables here: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/0ae545ebad1b6b2a6c851205854b887d19c8da59/Source/cmFindPackageCommand.cxx#L1270

I'll try to reword. Note that I cut variable names for readability. Let's boil it down to four cases:

- If `UNSUITABLE` set: discard package regardless other variables
- If `UNSUITABLE` not set, `EXACT` not set, `COMPATIBLE` not set: package is good if `find_package` did not request version (it doesn't matter with or without EXACT)
- If `UNSUITABLE` not set, `EXACT` not set, `COMPATIBLE` set: package is good if `find_package` did not require EXACT version
- If `UNSUITABLE` not set, `EXACT` set: package is good

So, `PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE` and `PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE` are not exclusive:

- `PACKAGE_VERSION_UNSUITABLE` discards package unconditionally
- `PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE` permits package only if EXACT not set and has no effect if `find_package` did not request version

Hope that helped =)